# Resolve complementary missing values between rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this

```
    Day ID              ID_2    AS  D   E    AS1    D1  E1  
29  72  Participant 1   PS 6 42 NaN NaN NaN  NaN    NaN NaN
35  78  Participant 1   NaN     yes 3   no   2      no  2   
49  22  Participant 2   PS 1 89 NaN NaN NaN  NaN    NaN NaN
85  18  Participant 2   NaN     yes 3   no   2      no  2
```

I'm looking for a way to add the `ID_2` column value to all rows where `ID` matches (i.e., for `Participant 1`, fill in the NaN values with the values from the other row where `ID`=`Participant 1`). I've looked into using `combine` but that doesn't seem to work for this particular case.

Expected output:

```
    Day ID              ID_2    AS  D   E    AS1    D1  E1  
29  72  Participant 1   PS 6 42 yes 3   no   2      no  2
35  78  Participant 1   PS 6 42 yes 3   no   2      no  2   
49  22  Participant 2   PS 1 89 yes 3   no   2      no  2
85  18  Participant 2   PS 1 89 yes 3   no   2      no  2
```

or

```
    Day ID              ID_2    AS  D   E    AS1    D1  E1  
29  72  Participant 1   PS 6 42 NaN NaN NaN  NaN    NaN NaN
35  78  Participant 1   PS 6 42 yes 3   no   2      no  2   
49  22  Participant 2   PS 1 89 NaN NaN NaN  NaN    NaN NaN
85  18  Participant 2   PS 1 89 yes 3   no   2      no  2
```

Comment: What do you mean to all rows where `ID` matches? Can we get an expected output?

Comment: @DarkDrassher34 Updated to make the question clearer. Basically for every given value of `ID`, fill in NaN values with non NaN values from the other rows with the same value for `ID`

Comment: Got it now. So you want in the first row and second row the same values?

Comment: @DarkDrassher34 Yes, specifically I'd like to fill in the NaN values with non NaN values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could try

```
df.ID_2 = df.groupby('ID').ID_2.ffill()

# 29    PS 6 42
# 35    PS 6 42
# 49    PS 1 89
# 85    PS 1 89
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to keep the additional columns in the dataframe

Comment: Just set `df.ID2 = df.groupby('ID').ID_2.ffill()` and it should keep the other columns :)

Comment: Yes, to be exact `df.ID_2 =... ` - thanks for pointing that out @DarkDrassher

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but something like this should work - can't copy your df into my browser.

```
print(df)
    Day             ID     ID_2   AS    D    E  AS1   D1   E1
0   72  Participant_1  PS_6_42  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   78  Participant_1      NaN  yes  3.0   no  2.0   no  2.0
2   22  Participant_2  PS_1_89  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   18  Participant_2      NaN  yes  3.0   no  2.0   no  2.0
df2 = df.set_index('ID').groupby('ID').transform('ffill').transform('bfill').reset_index()

print(df2)
   ID  Day     ID_2   AS  D   E  AS1  D1  E1
0  Participant_1   72  PS_6_42  yes  3  no    2  no   2
1  Participant_1   78  PS_6_42  yes  3  no    2  no   2
2  Participant_2   22  PS_1_89  yes  3  no    2  no   2
3  Participant_2   18  PS_1_89  yes  3  no    2  no   2
```